# English equivalent of this Telugu proverb

Tags: idiom-requests, proverb-requests

What English proverb can be matched to this Telugu proverb?

> **There is no harm in lying 1000 times in order to perform a single successful marriage**.

This is a famous proverb in Southern India, where arranged marriage is more prevalent than love marriage.

Is there any English proverb that is equivalent to this proverb or which describes about the hardships that are faced to successfully pull off a marriage?

Please don't edit my question, it is from Telugu language not tamil.

Comment: Can you explain what it means to "do one marriage"?

Comment: We really need a more explicit verb other than "do", and quickly before people start downvoting/flagging this.

Comment: Actually the saying is from Tamil, "Aayiram poi solli oru kalyanam pannalaam" meaning, "For one successful marriage, you can even lie 1000 times". But the real proverb is not this, The original version is, "Aayiram per-idam solli oru kalyaanam pannu". That means, "Spread the word to 1000 persons and perform a marriage. Don't engage yourself in a secret marriage". It has been changed in the recent years. Mostly in movies.

Comment: @NagarajanShanmuganathan thank you for sharing your insights. Can you kindly edit the question to reflect your thoughts?

Comment: It's not limited to Telugu and can be found in many Indian languages. I'm not so sure of its meaning.

Comment: @NagarajanShanmuganathan Are you sure your edit shows the correct meaning? I think this proverb actually means "the end justifies the means".

Comment: Any similarity with "all's fair in love and war"? i.e. When it comes to romantic relationships, the normal rules don't count.

Comment: I was informed about the transformation about the proverb's original intent when I was in school by my language teacher. I don't have the source. That is why I posted it as a comment.

Comment: Comment1 - As a native Tamil speaker, this proverb has gone a semantic shift of the original -"One may repeat the same lie a 1000 times so as to organize a successful marriage". It's not 1000 different lies but the same lie repeated a thousand times. Due to cultural influences and cinema, the original has undergone a transformation. This saying is mostly used as a playful mockery of sorts.

Comment: Comment2 - For example, let's say the bride can't cook well. The elder members of her family may try to conceal this fact and project her as a great cook to her potential in-laws family. So they can repeat the lie (that the bride is a great cook) a 1000 times for the alliance to come to fruition. To find an approximate equivalent , let alone an exact one in English would be a tough job. Good luck !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An equivalent expression in English is:

> [**The end justifies the means**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/The+end+justifies+the+means)

This means that no matter how immoral the process is, it is justified if the end result is appropriate.

For example, in the situation you are asking about, the *means* are the lies told and the *ends* is the marriage, and bringing the marriage into being  justifies the lies told.

(But that's a subject for [debate](http://www.debate.org/debates/The-ends-justify-the-means/1/)...)

> *Prov.* You can use bad or immoral methods as long as you accomplish something good by using them. (Not everyone agrees with this idea.)
>
> *Lucy got money for the orphanage by embezzling it from the firm where she worked. "The end justifies the means," she told herself.*
>
> *The politician clearly believed that the end justifies the means, since he used all kinds of nefarious means to get elected.*

Answer (score -1):

> "Aayiram poi solli oru kalyanam pannalaam" meaning, "For one successful marriage, you can even lie 1000 times".
>
> Comment from @NagarajanShanmuganathan above

As @Karl says, a good English proverb here would be, "All's fair in love and war".

> But the real proverb is not this, The original version is, "Aayiram per-idam solli oru kalyaanam pannu". That means, "Spread the word to 1000 persons and perform a marriage. Don't engage yourself in a secret marriage".
>
> Comment continued

This nicely maps to, ["Why would he buy the cow if he can get the milk for free?"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Why+buy+a+cow+when+you+can+get+milk+for+free%3F)

Comment: Not my dv. I don't think the "cow/milk" expression is suitable in this context.